# Add a column in PowerBI that finds the first instance of another column

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, powerquery

I have a table with data for projects that include phases, start dates, and end dates.

The problem I'm running into is when I build a visual to show the number of projects in the month of August broken down by phase, the total for the month of August is way off since one project could be in multiple phases for the month of August.

What I'd like is to find the first phase only at the start of a given month.

Example of data at the start:

| Project ID | Project Name | Phase | Start | Finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 |

What I have done is added a custom column using the Number.From function to find the number of days inbetween the Start and Finish dates (**DayInBetween)**. So there is a row for every day of the phases. Then, I added another custom column and used the Date.StartOfMonth function to return the month of the new added custom column (**MonthOfNewColumn)**

After:

| Project ID | Project Name | Phase | Start | Finish | DayInBetween | MonthOfNewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 | 8/1/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 | 8/2/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 | 8/3/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 | 8/4/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Initiation | 8/1/2022 | 8/25/2022 | 8/5/22 | August |

So this goes through all the days and then when it got to the next phase it would look like

| Project ID | Project Name | Phase | Start | Finish | DayInBetween | MonthOfNewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/26/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/27/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/28/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/29/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/30/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 8/31/22 | August |
| 123 | Project X | Planning | 8/26/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 9/1/22 | September |

If I go and build a bar chart to look at the total count of projects broken down by their phases, Project 123 is going to show up in the Initiation AND Planning phase for the month of August.

I only want it to count for the phase it was at the start of the month.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautiful, but seems to work

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project ID", Int64.Type}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Phase", type text}, {"Start", type date}, {"Finish", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Project ID","Phase"}, {
    {"Start", each  _[Start]{0}, type table},
    {"Month", each 
            List.Transform(
                {Number.From(List.First(List.Sort(_[Start]))) .. 
                Number.From(List.Last(List.Sort(List.Combine({_[Start],_[Finish]}))))}
            , each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From(_)))

    }}),
#"Expanded range" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Month"),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Expanded range", {"Project ID", "Month"}, {{"data", each Table.Sort(_,{{"Start", Order.Ascending}})[Phase]{0}, type text }}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows1",{{"Month", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]